# не дружит sqlite3 или с python3 или со мной

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite3

```
c = conn.cursor()
s = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ' + tabname + ' (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, date text, cat text, nameproduct text, price int);'
c.execute(s)
conn.commit()
c.executemany("INSERT INTO :tabname VALUES (date = :date, cat = :cat, nameproduct = :nameproduct price = :price)", {"tabname" : tabname, "date" : tableinsert[0], "cat" : tableinsert[1], "nameproduct" : tableinsert[2], "price" : tableinsert[3]})
```

этот код возвращает:

```
c.executemany("INSERT INTO :tabname VALUES (date = :date, cat = :cat, nameproduct = :nameproduct price = :price)", {"tabname" : tabname, "date" : tableinsert[0], "cat" : tableinsert[1], "nameproduct" : tableinsert[2], "price" : tableinsert[3]})
sqlite3.OperationalError: near ":tabname": syntax error
```

простой execute()возвращает то же самое
что я делаю не так?

Comment: Для имён таблиц такая подстановка не работает, используйте обычное сложение строк как в CREATE TABLE

Comment: (ну и естественно `tabname` должен быть из безопасного источника и/или экранирован, иначе SQL-инъекция)

Comment: а как тогда защита от инъекций? получается никак?

Comment: А зачем здесь защита от инъекций, вы получаете `tabname` от пользователя? А зачем вы получаете `tabname` от пользователя?

Comment: когда я где-нибудь пишу/говорю, что запросы передаю через строку(даже если формирую запросы сам внутри программы) мне пытаются бить лицо :) а тут вон где собака порылась. оформите комментарий как ответ

Comment: Так-то за имена таблиц из переменной лицо тоже можно бить :D Поэтому и спрашиваю, зачем. Скорее всего, вы что-то делаете неправильно и это всё вам просто не нужно

Comment: все запросы в данном случае формирую из программы, путь для и инъекции не вижу, просто решил что раз все так страшно ругаются - попробую методы из документации, но таблицы у меня заранее не известны, похоже мне этот метод не слишком подходит и буду решать проблемы по старинке, контролируя что ввожу :)